# what does "time and again" mean?

Tags: phrases

What does "time and again" mean in the following example?

> Time and again, I have seen a very good opportunity follow right on ...

Comment: Dictionaries define phrases as well as words: [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/time%20and%20again)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Time and again* means *over and over, repeatedly.*

> He has been scolded in front of the class time and again.
>
> Obama seems to have fooled the nation time and again.

Comment: The second is a bit loaded, no? You could also say "The American people have chosen to elect Obama time and again" except I would think time and again are more than twice

Comment: @mplungjan Sometimes you gotta be loaded;)

Comment: @mplungjan I agree that "time and again" implies more than twice, and probably also more than thrice.